# How to create a file in java without a extension

Tags: java, file, io

Is it possible in java to create a file without extension

Comment: Its no different then creating one with an extension.

Answer (score 10):

You can try

```
File f;
f=new File("myfile");
if(!f.exists()){
  f.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: will this create file without having extension.

Comment: @SureshS Yes it will.  The file created will have exactly the name in quotes - if you add an extension, it will have an extension on disk, otherwise it won't.  There is no default extension for the files you create in this manner.

Comment: @Suresh S - it won't if you don't try it!  :-)

Comment: @Suresh probably worth noting that creating a file without an extension will do nothing different than one created with an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's easy.  No different then doing it with an extension. So for example, if you have a string you want to write to a file, you can do

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("noExtension");
PrintStream printout = new PrintStream(out);
printout.println("Hello world!");
printout.close();
```

You could skip the PrintStream and do `out.write("Hello world!".getBytes());` if you wanted.