# java.io.File.createNewFile() method and file type

Tags: java, file-io

i know the method in `java.io.File.createNewFile()` will *Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist.*

**What is the extention of file which it creates if i just pass it the path ?**

```
try {
    String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() +
        "/databases";
    File f = new File(destPath);
    if (!f.exists()) 
    {               
        f.mkdirs();
        f.createNewFile();
          ........

    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: the extension is an arbitrary notion. in your case, there is just none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file does not in reality have a type. It is just bits. Your application/os view it as having a type based on some rules, for example a file extension in the name.

JSON is just a format for text, which is just a convention for how bits map to characters (see character sets). The binary formats for video, imagery, etc. are again conventions/standards that have some encoding to represent whatever they are representing.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a `File` you give it a name. The extension is just a part of that name. If you want a file named `Foo` that's a text file, then create a file `Foo.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide an extension, there's nothing added. Files without extensions are still files. You could open them with any text editor like you could open `.mp3` files with an editor, it just doesn't make very much sense.

So there will nothing be added to your path. The filename will just be your last segment of `"/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases"`, in this case: `databases`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a file with no extension

```
File f;
f=new File("myfile");
if(!f.exists()){
  f.createNewFile();
}
```

see  [How to create a file in java without a extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415185/how-to-create-a-file-in-java-without-a-extension)

To create a file with extension

```
 f = new File("myFile.txt");

 // tries to create new file in the system
  bool = f.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Other guys said if you do not explicitly provide an extension,it is created *without an extension* .

BTW I think if you would just run your code (or some example) you will see the result...